# AWS lambda gives timeout sometimes on endpoint "https://events.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I am using an AWS lambda to enable or disable eventbridge rule, the lambda works fine sometime, but some time it gives me:

> Error: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://events.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"

I used retry mechanism as well, using botocore config:

```
config = Config(connect_timeout=20, read_timeout=30, retries={"max_attempts": 10})
```

but it still gives me the same error.

Given: the behavior is not consistent some time it does what it suppose to do some time it gives me error.

I am expecting that you can either solve the problem or can explain me about this behavior.

Comment: Is the Lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: Generally inconsistent connectivity is due to configuring the lambda to run in multiple VPC subnets, some of which have NAT, and some of which do not.

Comment: Can you please more details about Lambda function and possible please share code to debug

Comment: Hi, This problem has been resolved, the problem was 
when I was trying put lambda in a vpc, I have selected all the subnet to execute my lambda. now some of my subnet is not configured to access the internet that is why when my lamda select that subnet it gave me time out and rest of the time it was executing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been resolved so I am going to give the solution to anyone in the future who may need it.

I have deployed my lambda in a vpc, while deploying it ask me to select some subnet I have selected all the subnet, now I have two types of subnet one is private and second is public. now what was happening, when my lambda was executing from private subnet it was giving me timout because it does not have internet connection and when public subnet was using for my lambda it was working fine. this was the reason for inconsistent execution of the lambda.